# Correctly use stencil_texturing in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, stencil-buffer

I am trying to implement the stencil_texturing extension of OpenGL as a proof of concept. My video card supports up to GL 4.3 so stencil_texturing is available to me. If more clarification is necessary here is the spec provided: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/stencil_texturing.txt.

So the goal of my test is to render my color buffer to a texture in frame 0, then the depth buffer in frame 1 and finally the stencil buffer in frame 2. The easy part is done and I have my color and depth buffer textures rendered fine. My issue lies with the stencil buffer and I believe the issue is coming from either my lack of understanding stencil buffers (which could very well be the case) or is my misuse of stencil_texturing. I tried to find some info online but there is very little available.

To give you an idea of what I am rendering here are my current frame captures:
[Color buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50eNx.jpg), [Depth buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhQR0.jpg), [Stencil buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qSr4.jpg)

So my vision for the stencil buffer is to just stencil out the middle triangle, so everything in the middle triangle has a value of 1 and every part of the texture has a value of 0. I am not sure how this will come up when rendering but I imagine the areas with a stencil value of 1 will be different than those with 0.

Here is my code below. It is just a test class that I throw into a framework I made for them. I believe the only thing not definied is GLERR() which basically calls glGetError() to make sure everything is correct.

```
   typedef struct
   {
     GLuint program;
     GLuint vshader;
     GLuint fshader;
   } StencilTexturingState;

   class TestStencilTexturing : public TestInfo
   {
    public:
    TestStencilTexturing(TestConfig& config, int argc, char** argv) 
        :width(config.windowWidth), height(config.windowHeight)
    { 
        state = (StencilTexturingState*) malloc(sizeof(StencilTexturingState));
    }

    ~TestStencilTexturing() 
    {
        destroyTestStencilTexturing();
    }

    void loadFBOShaders()
    {
        const char* vshader = "assets/stencil_texturing/fbo_vert.vs";
        const char* fshader = "assets/stencil_texturing/fbo_frag.fs";

        state->vshader = LoadShader(vshader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLERR();
        state->fshader = LoadShader(fshader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GLERR();
        state->program = Link(state->vshader, state->fshader, 1, "inPosition");
        GLERR();

        glUseProgram(state->program);
    }

    void loadTextureShaders()
    {
        const char* vshader = "assets/stencil_texturing/tex_vert.vs";
        const char* fshader = "assets/stencil_texturing/tex_frag.fs";

        state->vshader = LoadShader(vshader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLERR();
        state->fshader = LoadShader(fshader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GLERR();
        state->program = Link(state->vshader, state->fshader, 1, "inPosition");
        GLERR();

        glUseProgram(state->program);
    }

    void destroyTestStencilTexturing()
    {
        glUseProgram(0);
        glDeleteShader(state->vshader);
        glDeleteShader(state->fshader);
        glDeleteProgram(state->program);
        free(state);
    }

    void RenderToTexture(GLuint renderedTexture, int frame)
    {
        GLint  posId, colId;
        GLuint fboId, depth_stencil_rb;

        const float vertexFBOPositions[] = 
        {
            -0.7f, -0.7f,  0.5f,  1.0f,
            0.7f,  -0.7f,  0.5f,  1.0f,
            0.6f,  0.7f,   0.5f,  1.0f,
        };

        const float vertexFBOColors[] = 
        {
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        };

        // Load shaders for the FBO
        loadFBOShaders();

        // Setup the FBO
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        // Set up renderbuffer for depth_stencil formats.
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth_stencil_rb);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_stencil_rb);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, 
                                  GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_stencil_rb);

        // Depending on the frame bind the 2D texture differently.
        // Frame 0 - Color, Frame 1 - Depth, Frame 2 - Stencil
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        // Create our RGBA texture to render our color buffer into.
        if (frame == 0)
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture, 0);
        }

        // Create our Depth24_Stencil8 texture to render our depth buffer into.
        if (frame == 1)
        {
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 

            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, NULL);
            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture, 0); 
        }

        // Create our Depth24_Stencil8 texture and change depth_stencil_texture mode
        // to render our stencil buffer into.
        if (frame == 2)
        {
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST | GL_STENCIL_TEST);

            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, NULL);
            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture, 0); 
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_STENCIL_INDEX);
        }

        GLERR();

        GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
        if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        {
            printf("There is an error with the Framebuffer, fix it!\n");
        }
        GLERR();

        // Give the values of the position and color of our triangle to the shaders.
        posId = glGetAttribLocation(state->program, "position");
        colId = glGetAttribLocation(state->program, "color");
        GLERR();

        glVertexAttribPointer(posId, 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, vertexFBOPositions);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posId);
        glVertexAttribPointer(colId, 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, vertexFBOColors);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colId);

        // Clear the depth buffer back to 1.0f to draw our RGB stripes far back.
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (frame == 2)
        {
            glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 1, 0xFF); // never pass stencil test
            glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);  // replace stencil buffer values to ref=1
            glStencilMask(0xFF); // stencil buffer free to write
            glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);  // first clear stencil buffer by writing default stencil value (0) to all of stencil buffer.
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // at stencil shape pixel locations in stencil buffer replace stencil buffer values to ref = 1

            // no more modifying of stencil buffer on stencil and depth pass.
            glStencilMask(0x00);
            // can also be achieved by glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

            // stencil test: only pass stencil test at stencilValue == 1 (Assuming depth test would pass.) and write actual content to depth and color buffer only at stencil shape locations.
            glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
        }

        // Use the Scissors to clear the FBO with a RGB stripped pattern.
        glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
        glScissor(width * 0/3, 0, width * 1/3, height);
        glClearColor(0.54321f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.54321f); // Red
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glScissor(width * 1/3, 0, width * 2/3, height);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.65432f, 0.0f, 0.65432f); // Green
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glScissor(width * 2/3, 0, width * 3/3, height);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.98765f, 0.98765f); // Blue
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
        GLERR();

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GLERR();

        // Remove FBO and shaders and return to original viewport.
        glUseProgram(0);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glDeleteShader(state->vshader);
        glDeleteShader(state->fshader);
        glDeleteProgram(state->program);
        glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        GLERR();
    }

    void drawFrameTestStencilTexturing(int frame)
    {
        GLint  posLoc, texLoc;
        GLuint renderedTexture;

        const GLubyte indxBuf[] = {0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2};

        const float positions[] = 
        {
            -0.8f, -0.8f,
            -0.8f,  0.8f,
            0.8f, -0.8f,
            0.8f, 0.8f,
        };

        const float texCoords[] = 
        {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f
        };

        // Allocate and initialize the texture that will be rendered to, and then
        // textured onto a quad on the default framebuffer.
        glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);

        // Render to the texture using FBO.
        RenderToTexture(renderedTexture, frame);

        // Create and load shaders to draw the texture.
        loadTextureShaders();

        // Draw texture to the window.
        glClearColor(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        posLoc = glGetAttribLocation(state->program, "position");
        texLoc = glGetAttribLocation(state->program, "a_texCoords");

        glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, positions);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
        glVertexAttribPointer(texLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, texCoords);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texLoc);

        // Draw our generated texture onto a quad.
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indxBuf);
        glFlush();

        glDeleteTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
        GLERR();
    }

    void renderTest(int frame)
    {   
        drawFrameTestStencilTexturing(frame);
    }

private:
    StencilTexturingState* state;
    const int height, width;
};

RUN_TEST(StencilTexturing, "stencil_texturing", 2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST | GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

is not going to work, the GL enable enums are NOT bit values, but just enums, so you might enable something else, or just get some GL_INVALID_ENUM error, but you don't enable the stencil test here.

Comment: Ok thanks, my mistake on that one. I am now getting just my grey background and no black quad where my texture should be. At least its a step in the right direction! Thanks :)